# Run PowerShell-Script from C# Application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, powershell, console-application

I'm trying to execute a PowerShell script from a c# application. The script has to be executed under a special usercontext.

I've tried different scenarios some are working some not:

**1. direct call from PowerShell**

I've called the script directly from a ps-console which is running under the correct usercredentials.

```
C:\Scripts\GroupNewGroup.ps1 1
```

**Result:** Successfully running the script.

**2. from a c# console application**

I've called the script from a c# consoleapplication which is started under the correct usercredentials.

Code:

```
 string cmdArg = "C:\\Scripts\\GroupNewGroup.ps1 1"
 Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
 runspace.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
 runspace.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;


     runspace.Open();

 Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

 pipeline.Commands.AddScript(cmdArg);
 pipeline.Commands[0].MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.Error, PipelineResultTypes.Output);
 Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
 var error = pipeline.Error.ReadToEnd();
 runspace.Close();

 if (error.Count >= 1)
 {
     string errors = "";
     foreach (var Error in error)
     {
         errors = errors + " " + Error.ToString();
     }
 }
```

**Result:** No Success. And a lot of "Null-Array" exceptions.

**3. from a c# console application - code side impersonating**

(http://platinumdogs.me/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials)

I've called the script from a c# consoleapplication which is started under the correct usercredentials and the code contains impersonation.

Code:

```
using (new Impersonator("Administrator2", "domain", "testPW"))

                   {
  using (RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke()) 
{ 
    invoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"); 
} 

     string cmdArg = "C:\\Scripts\\GroupNewGroup.ps1 1";
     Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
     runspace.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
     runspace.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;


         runspace.Open();

     Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

     pipeline.Commands.AddScript(cmdArg);
     pipeline.Commands[0].MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.Error, PipelineResultTypes.Output);
     Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
     var error = pipeline.Error.ReadToEnd();
     runspace.Close();

     if (error.Count >= 1)
     {
         string errors = "";
         foreach (var Error in error)
         {
             errors = errors + " " + Error.ToString();
         }
     }
 }
```

**Results:**

- The term 'Get-Contact' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
  function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
  name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
  try again.
- The term 'C:\Scripts\FunctionsObjects.ps1' is not recognized as the
  name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
  the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
  path is correct and try again.
- No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 2.
  Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
- System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.0.0.0,
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
- Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The Web application
  at `http://XXXX/websites/Test4/` could not be found. Verify that you
  have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing
  content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL
  mapping to the intended application."
- You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. Cannot index
  into a null array.

**Until now there is no working answer**

Does anyone know why there are differences and how to solve the problem?

Comment: any final solution with full source code working ?

Comment: Avoid calling [RunSpace.Open() while impersonating](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22749094/939250).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

```
using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" ) ) 
{ 
    using (RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke()) 
    { 
        invoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"); 
    } 
}
```

Edit:

Found this little gem...  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User

```
namespace Tools
{
    #region Using directives.
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    using System;
    using System.Security.Principal;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    #endregion

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /// <summary>
    /// Impersonation of a user. Allows to execute code under another
    /// user context.
    /// Please note that the account that instantiates the Impersonator class
    /// needs to have the 'Act as part of operating system' privilege set.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>   
    /// This class is based on the information in the Microsoft knowledge base
    /// article http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q306158
    /// 
    /// Encapsulate an instance into a using-directive like e.g.:
    /// 
    ///     ...
    ///     using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" ) )
    ///     {
    ///         ...
    ///         [code that executes under the new context]
    ///         ...
    ///     }
    ///     ...
    /// 
    /// Please contact the author Uwe Keim (mailto:uwe.keim@zeta-software.de)
    /// for questions regarding this class.
    /// </remarks>
    public class Impersonator :
        IDisposable
    {
        #region Public methods.
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor. Starts the impersonation with the given credentials.
        /// Please note that the account that instantiates the Impersonator class
        /// needs to have the 'Act as part of operating system' privilege set.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName">The name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="domainName">The domain name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="password">The password of the user to act as.</param>
        public Impersonator(
            string userName,
            string domainName,
            string password )
        {
            ImpersonateValidUser( userName, domainName, password );
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        #endregion

        #region IDisposable member.
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        public void Dispose()
        {
            UndoImpersonation();
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        #endregion

        #region P/Invoke.
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        private static extern int LogonUser(
            string lpszUserName,
            string lpszDomain,
            string lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType,
            int dwLogonProvider,
            ref IntPtr phToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
        private static extern int DuplicateToken(
            IntPtr hToken,
            int impersonationLevel,
            ref IntPtr hNewToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
        private static extern bool RevertToSelf();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern  bool CloseHandle(
            IntPtr handle);

        private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
        private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        #endregion

        #region Private member.
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        /// <summary>
        /// Does the actual impersonation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName">The name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="domainName">The domain name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="password">The password of the user to act as.</param>
        private void ImpersonateValidUser(
            string userName, 
            string domain, 
            string password )
        {
            WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity = null;
            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

            try
            {
                if ( RevertToSelf() )
                {
                    if ( LogonUser(
                        userName, 
                        domain, 
                        password, 
                        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                        LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, 
                        ref token ) != 0 )
                    {
                        if ( DuplicateToken( token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate ) != 0 )
                        {
                            tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity( tokenDuplicate );
                            impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Win32Exception( Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() );
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception( Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception( Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() );
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if ( token!= IntPtr.Zero )
                {
                    CloseHandle( token );
                }
                if ( tokenDuplicate!=IntPtr.Zero )
                {
                    CloseHandle( tokenDuplicate );
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reverts the impersonation.
        /// </summary>
        private void UndoImpersonation()
        {
            if ( impersonationContext!=null )
            {
                impersonationContext.Undo();
            }   
        }

        private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        #endregion
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Comment: Yes I already set the ExecutionPolicy by hand. But I've tried it now in code but without any success: I've put it into my questions code.

Answer (score 6):

I just spent the day fixing this for myself.

I finally was able to make it work by adding **-Scope Process** to Set-ExecutionPolicy

```
invoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process");
```

Comment: thank you, this solved my problem after seeing that i had to use "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" on a hundred of sites, the -Scope Process did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

`Several PowerShell cmddlets take a PSCredential object to run using a particular user account`. May have a look at this article -
http://letitknow.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/run-powershell-script-using-another-account/

Here's how you can create the Credential object containing the username and password you want to use:

```
$username = 'domain\user'
$password = 'something'
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
```

Once you have the password ready for use in a credential object, you can do a number of things, such as call Start-Process to launch PowerShell.exe, specifying the credential in the -Credential parameter, or Invoke-Command to invoke a "remote" command locally, `specifying the credential in the -Credential parameter`, or you could call Start-Job to do the work as a background job, `passing the credentials you want into the -Credential parameter`.

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/koteshb/archive/2010/02/13/powershell-creating-a-pscredential-object.aspx) , [here](http://powergui.org/thread.jspa?threadID=13759) & in [msdn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714574.aspx) for [more information](http://letitknow.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/run-powershell-script-using-another-account/)