# Powershell command through C# code

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to add through C# code Powershell command or script (what is correct?) variable declaration with default value stored in C# variable.
For example, in Powershell I typing following line

```
 $user = 'Admin'
```

I want to add this line in C# code.

```
powershell.AddScript(String.Format("$user = \"{0}\"", userName));
```

or

```
powershell.AddCommand(String.Format("$user = \"{0}\"", userName));
```

I try with AddCommand() but it throws exception. I use PS 2.0.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `AddScript` method instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this article [How to run PowerShell scripts from C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C), you will need something like this:

```
// create Powershell runspace
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
// open it
runspace.Open();

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(String.Format("$user = \"{0}\"", userName));
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("#your main script");

// execute the script
Collection<psobject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
// close the runspace
runspace.Close();
```

Also see [Run Powershell-Script from C# Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120452/run-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-application) question here on Stackoverflow.