# 'Unauthorized operation' when executing Powershell.Invoke()

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

I am running the below code, as referenced from:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067260/invoke-powershell-command-from-c-sharp-with-different-credential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fltkm.png)

I believe all necessary code is shown below but basically when GetPSResults is called, a PSCredential object is passed in. The issue arises when I try to execute **ps.Invoke()**.

I am running this on localhost, running a Powershell script as a 'generic' user that has been created for use in this program (those credentials are set in the PSCredential object). This user has also been given 'admin' rights on my localhost. That user is trying to retrieve logs from a remote server.  Given the error, I am assuming this is some type of permissions issue but I am not extremely familiar with that side of things.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        GetLogs newGetLogs = new GetLogs();
        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(@"MYDOMAIN\MYUSERID", newGetLogs.GetSecurePassword("TESTPASSWORD"));

        Collection<PSObject> returnValues = GetPSResults(credential);

    }            
        public static Collection<PSObject> GetPSResults(PSCredential credential, bool throwErrors = true)
        {
            Collection<PSObject> toReturn = new Collection<PSObject>();
            WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
            connectionInfo.Credential = credential;

            using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
            {
                runspace.Open();
                using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    ps.Runspace = runspace;
                    ps.AddCommand("get-eventlog");
                    ps.AddParameter("ComputerName", "MYSERVERNAME");
                    ps.AddParameter("LogName", "MYLOGNAME");
                    ps.AddParameter("EntryType", "Error");
                    ps.AddParameter("Newest", 20);

                    toReturn = ps.Invoke();
                    if (throwErrors)
                    {
                        if (ps.HadErrors)
                        {
                            throw ps.Streams.Error.ElementAt(0).Exception;
                        }
                    }
                }
                runspace.Close();
            }

            return toReturn;
        }

        public SecureString GetSecurePassword(string password)
        {
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }

            return securePassword;
        }
```

I am getting this error:

> System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: 'Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.'

Within Visual Studio, I can drill down into the error to see the below image. I see that there are multiple mentions of Registry in these messages... is that a sign of some sort of permissions issue?

I have seen some mention of WinRM but I am not completely clear on the type of updates I would need to make... either in the code or on my user account(s).

Comment: Is there a reason you are calling PowerShell from C# instead of using the .NET methods for reading the Windows Event Log? (like [`EventLog.GetEventLogs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.geteventlogs)

Comment: I assume this is in a Windows service. What credentials is the service running under?

Comment: @GabrielLuci, great question. This particular app is planned to do some more involved operations, which will be easier with Powershell. Regarding your other question... Yes this is in a Windows service. If I understand you correctly, the service is running under localhost credentials.

Comment: Do you mean that it is a local user account? If you run "services.msc" and look at the list of services, there is a "Log on as" column. What is there for this service?

Comment: And I'd be curious to know what "more involved operations" are easier with PowerShell than through .NET. I have done PowerShell coding in C# before when I had no other choice (like with Microsoft Exchange and Office 365 administration) but it's awful. I have learned to avoid it at all costs.