# Has anyone successfully connected C# to Office 365 Exchange Online to create Public Calendar Appointments?

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, exchange-server, office365

Our company is trying to decide if going to Office 365 and "Exchange Online" makes sense.

I need to figure out if I can relatively easily modify our Winforms Applications created in C# 4.0 .NET Framework to use "Exchange Online" to create and delete Calendar Appointment on **Calendars in the Public Folders** and send email. From what I see online, impersonating a user and allowing them to modify/add/delete from public calendars can prove tricky.

I found a few articles that instantiate PowerShell from within C#: [Run Powershell-Script from C# Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120452/run-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-application) but was hoping for a more recent solution and was wondering if anyone has cleared this hurdle recently using  something like https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Windows-Start (but we use either Windows Server or Windows 7 (not 8.1 as is required by this github version).

If anyone has sent email and created/deleted appointments on calendars in the public folders using Office 365, please let me know how involved it was. Our current calendar and email creation classes are fairly straightforward. I just want to modify them to use Office 365's "Exchange Online" (Online Exchange Server)

Is there anyway I can test this without having access to "Exchange Online"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that when you state **Public Calendars**, you mean a calendar in a public folder. If so, you'll need to use [EWS and the EWS Managed API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945067).  That link will take you to information about accessing public folders. It is applicable to Office 365.

Without knowing more about your scenario, I'd suggest you [get started here to create a simple EWS client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx). This will work fine for WinForm. Then, go here and [bind to the top of the public folder hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn535504(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_getfolderewsma).

Change `Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, propSet);`

To `Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot, propSet);`

You can now [search the folder hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn535504(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_getfolderhierarchyewsma). You can also use [Folder.FindFolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee693718(v=exchg.80).aspx).

Here's your [information for working with your calendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn495623(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Here's your [information for working with your email](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn600185(v=exchg.150).aspx).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes -- I meant to say "Calendar in a public folder". I adjusted my question accordingly. Thanks for the suggestions. Is there anyway I can test this without having access to  "Exchange Online"?

Comment: I expect that the code will be the same for Exchange Online and on-premise as long as you are on Exchange 2013. You can test against Exchange Online. There are instructions on [how to get an Office 365 developer account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/setup-development-environment). Go to the **If you don't currently have an Office 365 for business account** for links.